# How to save tensorflow Google Cloud output to GCP SQL?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to run tensor flow from Google Cloud Platform. Is it possible to store tensor flow output directly to GCloud SQL database?

Comment: Which outputs are you interested in, specifically the event summaries?

Comment: For example, if i am running image recognition , will get output as the parameters, i want to store all those parameters in a table in google cloud sql?

Comment: There is not currently direct support for that. I'm interested in better understanding this interesting use case. Is the purpose for this to analyze the parameters via sql commands (min, max, mean, etc.)?